# await statement cause to call Application error method in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hy! I am working on my final year project in asp.net. but stuck in a problem. I have **Application_Error** method in **Global.asax.cs**  for any kind of exception.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("/Error/ErrorMessage");
        }
```

this method rendered at an await statement.

```
await service.StoreMessage(model);
```

I don't know what is happening hare ...... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe a breakpoint prior to clearing the message and reading the exception would be helpful

Comment: Please post the exception

Comment: and if it's an AggregateException please check the inner exception.

Comment: Yes i find the solution .... There was another problem in StoreMessage Fnction.